# Imploded PHP integer array for Mysql NOT IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've been trying to use a PHP integer array for a MySQL query that uses the `NOT IN` clause, but despite no errors it seems to always return the results I want filtered out.

Example:

```
$IDS = $_SESSION['Posts'];
$Select = 'SELECT * 
             FROM status 
            WHERE (W_ID = '.$ID.') 
              AND (ID NOT IN ("'.implode(',', $IDS).'")) 
         ORDER BY ID DESC 
            LIMIT '.$Begin.', '.$Number.'';

$Select = mysql_query($Select) OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

I'm pretty sure this is a logical syntax error.

What I've tested for:

I've made sure that $IDS is treated as an array. Also I have tested to see whether there are values stored within the array. I have also not quoted the integer array, but then I got a mysql syntax error for not having them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the two `”` in the beginning and the end of the `IN` block. They cause the entire implode array to become a comma-separated string.

Comment: Removing those still gives me an error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 20' at line 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM status WHERE (W_ID=3) AND (ID NOT IN (3, 4, 5, 6)) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 20 -- this SQL is perfect valid. Post yours please

Comment: Thanks I figured out that the initial value was blank for the first round  of the loop, your solution worked.

Comment: On input values also check mario’s answer. As he points out it is not always safe to rely on the input data.

Answer (score 3):

Your actual query will look like this:

```
ID NOT IN ("1,2,3,4")
```

`"1,2,3,4"` is *one string*, not several values. Get rid of the `"` quotes.

Comment: I was using this quite a long time but found some kind of strange behaviour. I have used `WHERE NOT IN(1,2,34,65,78,87,90,105)` which retuned something like `10,15,25,60,87,90` so it does not work properly.

Comment: how did you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `FIND_IN_SET` rather than an `IN` clause.

```
  $IDS = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $IDS));
  $Select = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE (W_ID=$ID)
             AND (NOT FIND_IN_SET(ID, '$IDS'))
             ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $Begin, $Number";
```

Anyway in SQL you are required to use single quotes for strings, not double quotes. That works with MySQL, but not for all configurations. Also gets more readable if you do it the other way round. (Single quotes in PHP for performance is retarded advise!)

Comment: the `NOT IN` user744319 is using is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes it's valid. It's advisable even. But this one is easier to work with and seems more appropriate for OP. (easier to secure also, not sure where the ID values originate from)

Comment: Sorry, was referring to FIND_IN_SET. Agree with you on the escape part. You should mention that point in your answer.